# How to compute local 3x3 range in a larger 2D matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, matrix

For an image processing workflow, I need to be able to apply a kernel to an image to create a new matrix as follows:

Iterate over an input 10x10 matrix, and at each location, determine the range (difference between maximum and minimum value) in a 3x3 neighborhood of the matrix element, and store this range at the corresponding location in a new 10x10 matrix. How can I do this?

If I have an example 4x4 matrix:

```
5 10 9 10
10 9 12 10
4 8 9 10
10 10 8 10
```

My function should get the range of a 3x3 subset of this matrix, centered around each of the 16 elements, and make a new 4x4 matrix of these ranges. The result on the above matrix should be:

```
5 7 3 3
6 8 4 3 
6 8 4 4
6 6 2 2
```

I'm trying to implement it in NumPy, but if it can be done in OpenCV or Skimage please let me know.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking, are you talking about some sort of convoluation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_neural_network

Comment: No, it's not clear what you're trying to do.  What does it mean algebraically to "iterate" one matrix over another?  This sounds like it might be a convolution operation or a simple dot-product, but you've avoided those terms.  You can clarify with illustrations or examples of the operation you have in mind.  Also include your coding attempt so far.

Comment: Yes, that's my definition of range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum value in a neighborhood is given by the morphological erosion, and the maximum value by the dilation. These can be computed by just about any image processing toolbox, including [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html#dilate), [SciKit](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.morphology.html#skimage.morphology.dilation) and my own [PyDIP](https://diplib.github.io/diplib-docs/group__morphology.html#ga8b73e434551895591068a9c18425d54a). Here I'll use [SciPy ndimage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.morphology.grey_dilation.html). The difference between the dilation and the erosion is what you refer to as "range".

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

# a is input array, here 5x5 because it's easy to display to the terminal
a = np.random.randint(30, size=(5,5))

mn = ndimage.grey_erosion(a, size=(3,3))
mx = ndimage.grey_dilation(a, size=(3,3))
b = mx - mn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
rows = arr.shape[0]
cols = arr.shape[1]

diff = np.zeros(shape=(rows,cols))

for i in range(rows):
    for j in range(cols):
         if i == 0:
            if j== 0:
                a = arr[i:i+2, j:j+2]
                diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
            elif j == cols:
                a = arr[i:i+2, j-1:j+1]
                diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
            else:
                a = arr[i:i+2, j-1:j+2]
                diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
        elif i == rows:
            if j== 0:
                a = arr[i-1:i+1, j:j+2]
                diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
            elif j == cols:
                a = arr[i-1:i+1, j-1:j+1]
                diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
            else:
                a = arr[i-1:i+1, j-1:j+2]
                diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
        elif j == 0:
            a = arr[i-1:i+2, j:j+2]
            diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
        elif j == cols:
            a = arr[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+1]
            diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
        else:
            a = arr[i-1:i+2, j-1:j+2]
            diff[i][j] = np.amax(a) - np.amin(a)
```

print(diff)

Comment: This is a longer one but can be modified according to the need. 'diff' matrix can be calculated as required (here it is diff = max - min).